# How to store latitude and longitude in a table in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm a new programmer. I know how to get the latitude/longitude and how to save items in core data, but I'm not sure how to save latitude and longitude.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeM7Zw12wbM

I've been watching this tutorial because I want a similar app, but I want to save latitude and longitude too. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

CoreData supports a wide range of number size values. Apple's preferred data type to store latitude and longitudinal values is a `CLLocationDegrees` object, which has a `typealias` of `Double`. So you would store your latitude and longitude values as `Double`'s inside CoreData.

In terms of how your CoreData `NSManagedObjectModel` should be set up, it would make the most sense to save the coordinates by location. In this case you would have two entities: a location entity with a name property that stores the location as a `string`, and a coordinate entity with both a latitude and longitude property that stores their corresponding values as a `Double`. You would need to create a "one to many" relationship linking your location to your coordinates.

Then to retrieve your coordinates you would send a fetch request to your location entity and then simply retrieve each location of type `NSManagedObject`'s corresponding coordinates.

You said you were a new programmer, so know that `CoreData` is not something to be taken lightly. I recommend you read through Apple's programming guide for Core Data as it explains how to set up your `CoreData` stack, `NSManagedObjectModel`, and how to create relationships between two entities; Which I am thinking you will most likely need to relate your location to your coordinates. Good Luck.

[Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1)